# How to download dropbox csv file to pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, import, dropbox

I'm unfamiliar with webscraping. I found some instructions, but I'm not sure what else to do from here. Clicking on the link downloads the csv file automatically. How do I get it to my pandas jupyter notebook by webscraping?

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/.../movie_data.csv'
u = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = u.read()
u.close()

with open('movie_data.csv', "wb") as f :
   f.write(data)
```

Comment: so you want or you don't want to download the csv file?

Comment: @NicoAlbers I mean I don't want to download the csv file into my directory since I plan on emailing my work. Having a 50+ mb zip file is not going to workout.

Comment: Okay, please do not remove that line on which I referred, rather change it to that meaning ;-)

Comment: @NicoAlbers Why? I clarified my intentions. ??

Comment: I think it's personal feeling from my side, but it's better to have the question extended than answering in comments, so one can see easily without reading comments. And your comment helps a lot to understand your original intentions, so it should be added to the question.

Comment: @NicoAlbers Thanks, but I figured it out myself.

Answer (score 19):

Figured it out. You need to append < ?dl=1 > to the end of your url like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/asdfasdfasfasdf/movie_data.csv?dl=1")
```

Comment: works like a charm.
my initial url that i got from Dropbox was :
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/asdfasdfasfasdf/movie_data.csv?dl=0"

which when I changed to : 

"https://www.dropbox.com/s/asdfasdfasfasdf/movie_data.csv?dl=1"
worked perfectly.


Thanks!

Comment: I got the url like dropbox.com/s/f/sdfsdfdsf.xlsx?rlkey=sfsdfasdfsaf&dl=1, I tried with pd.read_excel, it throwing certificate error, I also tried with removing rlkey,but same error