# How can I read a csv file from Dropbox Online?

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

How can I read a csv file from Dropbox Online (without downloading it to local machine)?

I installed and imported `dropbox` in Python, created an app and got a token from "https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps". While I read some resources online, I am still fuzzy on how I move from here.

Comment: You need to download to your machine. That is how any HTTP request works. That being said, what is unclear from the documentation?

Comment: I assume he means that he doesn't want to download it to the filesystem, as many API calls will provide that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Line `149` on the example here provides a function that downloads a file and returns it as a byte string.

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/main/example/updown.py

Then just parse the byte string, for example using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
from example.updown import download   # import the download function from updown.py, or copy or replicate that function, I'm only providing pseudo code here

file_as_bytes = download(dbx, folder, subfolder, name)
df = pd.read_csv(file_as_bytes)
print(df)
```

Comment: I feel like using `dbx.files_download(path)` from the actual installed module would be better than downloading the examples folder and importing one function from it

Comment: The way I'm reading the question, the OP wants to explicitly avoid the round trip to the local filesystem. Perhaps this point could be clarified.

Comment: Based on the comments in the file linked, the bytes are returned. Nothing is written to disk

Comment: You're right then. That's a better way to present the answer, but I don't know how to do the authentication in dropbox off the top of my head, which is why I leaned on the example that had all of those details. If someone else wants to post a more complete answer that would be better and I can remove this one.

Comment: Look at line 67. OP states they have a token.

Comment: @DavidParks Thank you so much for your answer, and I apologize for the late response. I will try it and make a comment on how it went.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for your comments on it. I will try what you suggested as well!

Answer (score 0):

Think as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987634/how-to-download-dropbox-csv-file-to-pandas) you can just read directly over the URL (but you need to change the arg from `?dl=0` to `?dl=1`

e.g.

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/asdfasdfasfasdf/movie_data.csv?dl=1")
```