# Problem reading CSV file from URL in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read csv file in pandas from this url:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uh7o7uyeghqkhoy/diabetes.csv

By doing this:

```py
url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/uh7o7uyeghqkhoy/diabetes.csv">
c = pd.read_csv(url)
```

Or by doing this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv"
s=requests.get(url).content
c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```

And i still get the same error message:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2
```

Comment: Your csv is likely malformed

Comment: Not really @GuillemB, look at my answer. The csv is in dropbox, therefore making it harder to access

Comment: If my answer helped, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark beside my answer and upvoting! :3

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/uh7o7uyeghqkhoy/diabetes.csv?dl=1")
print(df)
```

You require a `?dl=1` at the end of your link.

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987634/how-to-download-dropbox-csv-file-to-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Add `?dl=1` to the end of the URL

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/uh7o7uyeghqkhoy/diabetes.csv?dl=1"
c = pd.read_csv(url)

print(c)
```

[How to download dropbox csv file to pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987634/how-to-download-dropbox-csv-file-to-pandas)